# schema.org with two domains/websites: main site and shop site

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I have two websites: `www.mycompany.com` and `shopmycompany.com` (not a subdomain) and would like to publish the relationship between them using schema.org. At present the `www.mycompany.com` identifies itself as an `Organization` and `shopmycompany.com` as a `WebSite` but there is no linkage between them. What would be best practices to present that connection?

Comment: Why do the domains matter? How would you link them if the websites were on the same domain?

Comment: Domains might not matter, I just wanted to make it clear that there isn't an implicit ownership linkage based on the shared (root) domain.

Comment: What does the content of both websites have in common?

Comment: The main site is a general corporate home page whereas the shop site it just an eCom site. There will be some overlap in visuals and some sections of copy describing the product.

Answer (score 0):

Just from a quick skimming of https://schema.org/WebSite, there are multiple properties that would be fine as linking the website with the company:

- [author](https://schema.org/author)/[creator](https://schema.org/creator)
- [maintainer](https://schema.org/maintainer)
- [provider](https://schema.org/provider)
- [publisher](https://schema.org/publisher)

However, I wonder whether the Shop really should classified as a WebSite (which is a CreativeWork) and not rather as a [Store](https://schema.org/Store) which may simply have a [parentOrganisation](https://schema.org/parentOrganization).
Yet another alternative would be to classify it as a [Service](https://schema.org/Service), which is [provided](https://schema.org/provider) by the Organisation and can [offer](https://schema.org/offers) things.
And yet another alternative could be to classify the shop website as the [OfferCatalog](https://schema.org/OfferCatalog) of offers made by the company.

Comment: There is a [`OnlineStore`](https://schema.org/OnlineStore) that is pending (described as "An eCommerce site"). Let's say I want to use that once available, what would be the right metadata to put on each of the two sites? Would it be the parent org declaring it self and the `subOrganization` and the shop site declaring it self and the `parentOrganization`? Would `department` be better than `subOrganization`?

Comment: Yes, I'd put the subject declaration and the property on each page; you can't have too much info imo (until they contradict each other, but I don't think schema.org types have that much scrutiny). I'd definitely use `subOrganisation` and `parentOrganisation`, doesn't sound like a department to me but you could use that as well.